# Kill process by ID in argument on windows

Tags: c, process, operating-system, terminate

I would like to write a program which kills process by Id. 
When I run it by name.exe [pid], it not working. Here is my code:

```
      int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        DWORD pid = argv[1];
        HANDLE handleOfMyProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_TERMINATE, FALSE, pid);
        TerminateProcess(handleOfMyProcess, 5);
    }
```

When I don't write line

```
DWORD pid = argv[1];
```

and give pid number as third argument, for example 1243 in this way:

```
HANDLE handleOfMyProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_TERMINATE, FALSE, 1243);
```

it works.

My question is why the first way doesn't work ?

Comment: `DWORD pid = atio(argv[1]);` would be better (even if atoi sucks, it sucks less than converting a char pointer to a DWORD)

Comment: argv[1] is a string (char *) you should convert it to an int.

Comment: not so bad a question, though (ok OP should read the warning but maybe he/she's using Turbo C :))

Answer (score 2):

Because the arguments of main are strings, you cannot assign an argument directly to a `DWORD`; you will have to convert it.

The definition of `main` shows this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]);
```

You can convert it with `atoi`:

```
    DWORD pid= atoi(argv[1]);
```

And you must turn warnings of your compiler on because the compiler would have given you a warning

Comment: I wanted to ask you to answer. not so bad a question, and okay answer. Maybe you could elaborate on why it still compiles (pointer => DWORD)